# How to change Url of website with user's name, ID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, next.js, wildcard-subdomain

I want to change the url of my website with the user's name so that user can share the url with his/her networks no name of the company/website included.

let's use upwork "www.upwork.com" for the example so when a freelancer signup on upwork or fiverr it creates their profile and then anyone can asses their profile with url like this "www.upwork.com/freelancerName-123" now instead of this i want to make it something like this "www.freelancerName-123.com" now freelancer can share their profile without showing the name of company in the url, help me achieve it I know there are many senior devs out there who can help :)

NOTE: I am using (reactjs/nextjs/firebase).

here's what CHAT-GPT says:
To give each user a unique URL after sign-up, you will need to dynamically generate a new domain name for each user and configure your web server to route requests to the appropriate user profile based on the domain name.
I need more clear answer

Comment: What you're trying to do is actually kind of difficult to do without manual maintenance for each domain name, and none of the technologies you listed are going to be able to help you here.  Firebase Hosting can't generate dynamic domain names.

Comment: Hey Spidey, hope this message finds you well, As Doug said, this is really hardcore and advanced, but here is a tutorial using nextjs + prisma + planetscale - https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application

Comment: Thanks Alot guys! for explaining and special thanks to Pedro that's exactly what I wanted, Kudos to you